# Start an Activity form a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I searched in site and there were similar questions as mine but none of theme were not my answer

look at this picture:

[image]

so it is clear that i want to start `CrimeActivity` by sending an `intent` from `CrimeListFragment` + an `extra` in its `intent`

the book that i read for android programming its author said:

> Starting an activity from a fragment works nearly the same as starting an activity from another activity.
>   You call the Fragment.startActivity(Intent) method, which calls the corresponding Activity
>   method behind the scenes

**CrimeListFragment.java :**

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   // Get the Crime from the adapter
   Crime c = ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

   // Start CrimeActivity
   Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimeActivity.class);
   i.putExtra(CrimeFragment.EXTRA_CRIME_ID, c.getId());
   startActivity(i);
}
```

the second part is now retrieving the `intent` and its `extra` and the author said about that:

> There are two ways a fragment can access data in its activity’s intent: an easy, direct shortcut and a
>   complex, flexible implementation. First, you are going to try out the shortcut. Then you will implement
>   the complex and flexible solution that involves fragment arguments.

and my problem is about the first way, the shortcut

> In the shortcut, CrimeFragment will simply use the getActivity() method to access the
>   CrimeActivity’s intent directly. Return to CrimeFragment and add the key for the extra. Then, in
>   onCreate(Bundle), retrieve the extra from CrimeActivity’s intent and use it to fetch the Crime

**CrimeFragment.java :**

```
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
  public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID =
    "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.crime_id";
  private Crime mCrime;
  ...
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mCrime = new Crime();
    UUID crimeId = (UUID)getActivity().getIntent()
      .getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

    mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
}
```

**The downside to direct retrieval**

> Having the fragment access the intent that belongs to the hosting activity makes for simple code.
>   However, it costs you the encapsulation of your fragment. CrimeFragment is no longer a reusable
>   building block because it expects that it will always be hosted by an activity whose Intent defines an
>   extra named EXTRA_CRIME_ID.
>
> This may be a reasonable expectation on CrimeFragment’s part, but it
>   means that CrimeFragment, as currently written, cannot be used with
>   just any activity.

My question and problem is the last sentence, why this Fragment (`CrimeFragment`) cannot be used with just any `Activity`???

Comment: use getActivity() from the fragment to start the new activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author explains it. Your `CrimeFragment`, in its `onCreate()` method, gets its hosting activity (through `getActivity()`) and then attempts to get an UUID from the `Intent` used to start that `Activity`.

This means that any activity containing your `CrimeFragment` now has to obey this rule, i.e. its intent should have (in it) an extra defined by the name `EXTRA_CRIME_ID`. If that activity does not comply, you'll see an exception being thrown in `CrimeFragment`'s `onCreate()`.

Try having this fragment in a new activity created by yourself to see what happens.

Comment: but as you can see we defined `EXTRA_CRIME_ID` in `CrimeFragment`, not in its containing Activity

Comment: the `EXTRA_CRIME_ID` `String` itself is defined in the fragment, but you're actually trying to get an extra from the `Activity`'s `Intent` that has that name. the real issue here is this one: if the `Activity` that contains the `CrimeFragment` does not have an `Intent` with that extra, you will see a crash. if you replace `EXTRA_CRIME_ID` for `"JOHN SMITH"` you still have the need for the `Activity`'s `Intent` to have the same extra.

Comment: so you mean actually there are 2 passing `intent`, the first one is from `CrimeListFragment` to `CrimActivity` and the second one is from `CrimeActivity` to `CrimeFragment` ???

Comment: no. precisely the opposite: just one `Intent`. in `onListItemClick()` you pass the extra to `CrimeActivity`, through an `Intent`. `CrimeFragment` (hosted by `CrimeActivity`) gets that extra - `getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID)` - because it knows/assumes its hosted by `CrimeActivity`. if you now wanted to use `CrimeFragment` in, let's say, `PoliceActivity`, `PoliceActivity` would have to be started the same way, i.e. with an `Intent` containing a `Crime` ID with the same name. try creating `PoliceActivity` containing `CrimeFragment` and start it without any extras.

Answer (score 0):

retrieval in onActivityCreated()

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        ....
    }
    else {
        UUID crimeId = (UUID)getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
    }
}
```